# Find the minimum value of the function a(x).

Tags: extreme-value-theorem, extreme-value-analysis

$$a(x)= \sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt{x^{-3}}-4(x+\frac{1}{x})$$

> One of the ways I could think of was to find out the global extreme
>       values and proceed.But as I began doing it that it takes a lot of
>        efforts and time. Is there a simpler way to proceed?
>   Further please suggest better tags if needed.

Comment: It does have a minimum value... Observe that the function is not defined over all reals. The minimum value is -10 as a matter of fact. (As per graphing calc)

Comment: You're right. I messed up the expression when I graphed it.

Comment: It's alright...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x\gt 0$, we can pick $y\gt 0$ such that $x=y^2$; then the given expression becomes $$(y + {1\over y})^3 - 3(y+{1\over y}) - 4(y+{1\over y})^2 + 8$$
That's equivalent to finding the minimum of 
$$t^3-4t^2-3t+8$$
for $t\ge 2$

Comment: Nicely done. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I feel th approach used here has its own restrictions as well.

Comment: yw:) I'm still hoping somebody posts a more elegant method using AM-GM...

Comment: Hmm. That would be nice.

Comment: @DareDevil right, domain restrictions apply. updated the ans

Comment: Nice approach. We could directly set $t=\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, giving us the same expression in terms of $t$.

Comment: here t also is greater than or equal to 2 not just greater than 0.(Using AM-GM on positive quantities)

Comment: @bjorn93 Oh yes, that looks way better! sleep time here in India haha

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is $$\sqrt{x^3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}-4\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\geq -10$$ and this is equivalent to
$$\frac{(x-1)^2(1-7x+x^2)^2}{x^3}\geq 0$$

Comment: Where did you get the -10 from?

Comment: I got it by calculus, what else?

Comment: Method I'm asking about..

Comment: Differentiating and solving $a'(x)=0$ for $x$

Comment: That method I get and understand but i was looking for an alternative to it. Or may be i don't understand exactly what you wish to convey. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: At first i tried to use $$a+\frac{1}{a}\geq 2$$ for $a>0$.

Comment: Hmm I tried that way but I couldn't get anything useful